# Objective C encryption code not working like Android AES 256, md5 encryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes, md5

I am encrypting a text to send server using `"AES256/PKCS5Padding/ECB"` encryption. The following code for Android works well so that the encrypted data is properly decrypted in NodeJS server.

```java
public static String encryptAES_Java_Node(String content, String key) {
 
              byte[] input;
              String query = null;
              try {
                     input = content.getBytes("utf-8");
 
                     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                     byte[] thedigest = md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                     SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest,
                                  "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc);
 
                     byte[] cipherText = newbyte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
                     int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
                     ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
 
                     query = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    
              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return query;
 
       }
```

Here is my code in ObjC

```c
(NSString *)encryptText:(NSString *)rawText withKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)


    NSData *rawData = [rawText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Convert to hash
    NSString *md5Key = [self MD5String:key];

    // fetch key data
    [md5Key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [rawData length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [rawData bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        NSData *tempData  = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        NSString* encrypted64 = [tempData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];//Even i have tried base 64 encding with other options available
        return encrypted64;
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

Am I making a mistake while converting key to MD5 as done in android?

Adding code for decryption in NodeJS service for reference.

```js
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', encryption_key);

            chunks = []
            chunks.push( decipher.update( new Buffer(fullBuffer, "base64").toString("binary")) );
            chunks.push( decipher.final('binary') );
            var txt = chunks.join("");
            txt = new Buffer(txt, "binary").toString("utf-8");

// where encryption_key = key, fullBuffer is the input and txt is output
```

Comment: With Android, you get the MD5 as a byte array. With iOS, you get the MD5 (most likely) as its string representation.

Comment: You may want to consider using an encrypted network protocol instead of using crypto primitives yourself. Cryptography is both critical and hard to get right.

Comment: "not working" is not an error description. SO is not an online debugger; please show what you have tried/where you are stuck.

Comment: @zneak iOS MD5 expects data in and produces data out, not strings. By data it is a 8-bit sequence of bytes: `unsigned char *`.

Comment: @zaph, the code here is `NSString *md5Key = [self MD5String:key]`.

Comment: @zneak iOS is as I said, just data. The method `[self MD5String:key]` is not iOS, is is some home grown code. The iOS Common Crypto call is: `unsigned char *CC_MD5(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md)`.

Comment: I meant that his iOS code got the MD5 as a string, not that the iOS framework normally produces a string. I was explaining the difference between his two implementations.

Comment: @Gabby hex log the key data, data in and encrypted data out for each immediately prior to and after the encryption call. Add that to the question. It the inputs are different work on that. If the encrypted data is different look at the options carefully. Is the key exactly 32 bytes for each? The Java is choosing the key size based on the supplied key, the iOS code is explicitly setting 256-bits. If the key are not both 32-bytes then the encryption will be adding padding and that may be different. All these are simple functions, just get the inputs correct and the outputs will correct output.

Comment: @zneak: Even if i use data to get MD5 result, i couldn't get the same encrypted output as JAVA. Does iOS encryption settings matches the one in JAVA ??

Answer (score 0):

MD5 produces a 16-byte result.

The Java will see this key and use AES128  which uses a 16-byte key. It would be better to explicitly specify key size in the Java version by using: `"AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)"`.

The iOS version is explicitly specifying AES256 which uses a 32-byte key and will null pad the 16-byts to 32-bytes.

In the iOS version change the encryption to AES16: `kCCKeySizeAES128`.

There are security issues:

1. Using MD5 to create a key from a string is not secure, the current practice is to use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 where the iteration count and random salt are passed pre-pended to the encrypted data.
2. ECB mode is not very secure, it is much better to use CBC mode with a random iv and pre-pend the iv to the encrypted data.

   But if security is not important MD5 and ECB are fine.

Comment: Any mistakes in my logic ? It would be helpful if you could show some code,  such that i get the same output for iOS ..

Comment: Null padding "123456" does not produce "12345600000000000000000000000000", those "0" characters are numeric zero: 0x30, not 0x00.

Comment: What do you mean by "salt" in: salt is "12345600000000000000000000000000". Encryption key? There is a difference between key and salt. If the key being used in "12345" the Java will most likely pad to 16-bytes and use AES128. The iOS explicitly specifies AES256 which is a 32-byte key.

Comment: Please provide the data I requested in my last comment to the question.